# Invoke Windows Workflow Recursively

Tags: recursion, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a workflow, that at a certain point, needs to be triggered recursively.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I tried the following code but *context* ends up being null??

```
private void codeTriggerChildren_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActivityExecutionContext context = sender as ActivityExecutionContext;
    //context is null here?!

    IStartWorkflow aWorkflow = context.GetService(typeof(ApprovalFlow)) as IStartWorkflow;

    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("Parm1", "foo");
    parameters.Add("Parm2", "bar");

    Guid guid = aWorkflow.StartWorkflow(typeof(ApprovalFlow), parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily the problem here is that the sender in this case is a `CodeActivity` not an `ActivityExecutionContext`.  So this code fails at the first hurdle.

Here is an example of custom activity that can do what you are after:-

```
public class RecurseApproval : Activity
{
    protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        IStartWorkflow aWorkflow = executionContext.GetService(typeof(IStartWorkflow)) as IStartWorkflow;

        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("Param1", "Foo");
        parameters.Add("Param2", "bar");

        Guid guid = aWorkflow.StartWorkflow(typeof(ApprovalWorkflow), parameters);

        return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;

    }
}
```

Note that the GetService gets type of `IStartWorkflow`.

Comment: And how do I create and execute that activity in code?  The issue is the initial workflow needs to split itself into several children all running the same workflow.

Comment: You'd give this custom activity some dependency properties to feed the properties going into the workflow.  You would then use a parrallel or a replicator activity to run this activity wiring up the properties accordingly.  Finer control would require quite a tricky custom composite activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your sender is of type CodeActivity not ActivityExecutionContext. You need to create a custom activity and override the Execute method which will pass you a ActivityExecutionContext.

Comment: How?  I added an activity to the workflow diagram and I can't do anything with it